# Read and Write a global array (vec3) in multiple files

Tags: javascript, html

If I initialize an array in *first.js* like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
export { arr };
```

Or like this:

```
var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
export { arr };
```

And try to use it in *second.js* like this:

```
import { arr } from "./first.js";
```

My array will undefined in second.js. :(

If I use the global variable **window** in *first.js* like this:

```
window.arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
```

If I try to use it in *second.js* the array will undefined too:(

How to properly share an array between files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first.js

```
export const array = [1, 2, 3];
```

second.js

```
import { array } from './first.js';
console.log(array); // Output: [1, 2, 3]
```